# How to fix " ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined " in linux. (Node.js App)

Tags: linux, foreach, typeerror

I have a Node.js application running without any error on Windows. The same app gives this error when I try to run in Linux:

```
ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

Can someone help with the error?

```
dirs.forEach(function (element) {
    fs.readdir(`${logPath}\\${element}`, (err, files) => {
        //console.log(`-${element}`);
        files.forEach(file => {
            //console.log(`|--${file}`);
            let fileDate = parseInt((file.split("_").join("")).split(".txt").join("")); //REMOVE '_' AND '.txt' FROM FILE NAME
            if (!isNaN(fileDate)) {
                if (fileDate < deleteFilesBefore) { 
                    fs.unlink(`${logPath}\\${element}\\${file}`, function(error) {
                        if (error) {
                            throw error;
                        }
                        console.log(`Deleted ${logPath}\\${element}\\${file}`);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Pretty hard without telling more. We don't see the stack trace. What exactly is "undefined" here on which `forEach` is called?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out bro.. I have edited the question

Comment: seems to me you are listing directories and or files in at a location. My bet is that under linux, the path may not be correct...?

Comment: @PhoenixBlue path for/of what ? Im not getting you. ( I made a project on Windows (Visual studio 17). I copied the project's zip file to my linux server through secure copy SCP cmd and then i unzipped it ) Can there be some error due to path or location after all this??

Comment: What I meant was, since you are apparently trying to list directories at a location,you set `logPath` to something like `C:\projects`, which would be invalid under Linux. Again, this is pure speculation, as we don't have the whole code

Comment: @PhoenixBlue . Belated Thanks Bro. Solved out the error that day itself forgot to thank uh, remembered today so came to thank uh.. Gratitude :)